# push_back into vector within hash map class

Tags: c++, vector, hashmap

I am trying to use the following main to test a HashMap class that I modified.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "HashMap.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    HashMap<int,vector<string>> hash(20);
    vector<string> vec;

    cout<<"Inserting item... ";
    if(hash.insert(2)){
       cout<<"successful. ";
       hash.find(2).push_back("word ");
       hash.find(2).push_back("is ");
       hash.find(2).push_back("pushed ");
       hash.find(2).push_back("back. ");
       hash.find(2).push_back("yes!\n");
    } else {
       cout<<" unsuccessful.";
       return 0;
    }
    vec = hash.find(2);

    for(auto& words: vec)
       cout<< words<<endl;;

    return 0;
}
```

The final for loop doesn't print anything.

The `find` function is defined like this:

```
Data find(const Key& key) { return array[findPos( key )].data_; }
```

where `Data` is the second template variable in the HashMap class. I ran a couple of tests and `find` returns empty vectors, even after using `push_back`. why is that? what can i do to push items into the vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `find` function returns a *copy* of the value inside your data structure. Specifically,

```
 Data find(const Key& key) { return array[findPos( key )].data_; }
```

Returns a `Data` *value*, which is to say that the compiler copies the value in the return statement to the local variable for the function call. I.e., each call to `hash.find(2)` is giving a fresh copy of an empty vector. You're then modifying the newly created empty vector. After the `push_back` finishes, the vector gets destructed since there is no lvalue to which it is bound; it is a temporary.

Modifying your function to:

```
 Data& find(const Key& key) { return array[findPos( key )].data_; }
```

Will accomplish what you'd like since it would return a *reference* to the internal data structure. Note that there are some associated dangers with doing so. This makes concurrent access harder to detect, allows users to gain references which may be invalidated (for instance, if you resize `array`), and generally violates encapsulation. However, it's the way to go if you're making a hash map with mutable values.

Comment: how would i make it so that references don't get invalidated?

Comment: You'd need to create your own iterator type which save a (shared) pointer to the original object - that will let you access the array once reallocation occurs. This is nontrivial, slower, and probably unnecessary to do, though, since you can just require (as the standard does) that references are only used until the next insertion.